# How to implement a particular division operator in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

Implement the division operator in a way that: **A is 12 div 6 div 2** result is: **A = 4**

So I think that I have to create an **infix operator** belonging to the type: **yfx** because this operator have first to calculate 6 div 2 and then calculate 12 div result(6 div 2)

I hope to be clear in my explanation...I know that I have explained the concept in a procedural way, but I did not know how else to express the precedence of the operations to be performed on arguments...

Ok, so I think (I hope) that the **yfx** form of operator is correct...

The problem is that now I don't know how to describe this operator.

In a previous exercise I have defined operator in this way:

```
op(600,xfx,has).

/* perter has information */
has(peter, information).
```

As I can read on Ivan Bratko book:

> **The operator definitions do not specify any operation or action. *In principle, no operation or data is associated with an operator.***

So I think that I can't define an operator that performs calculations.

So I think that a solution of my exercise could be something like:

```
op(600,yfx,div).

div(X div Y, Division) :- Division is X/Y.
```

But don't work well and moreover I think that this is not that they asking me to implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

div appears to be a predeclared operator, already doing integer division, then it's sufficient to change its associativity.

Here it's the default:

```
?- current_op(P,A,div).
P = 400,
A = yfx.
```

behaving

```
?-  A is 12 div 6 div 2.
A = 1.
```

change as you like:

```
?- [user].
|: :-op(400,xfy,div).
|: % user://1 compiled 0,04 sec, 1 clauses
true.
```

and you'll get

```
?- A is 12 div 6 div 2.
A = 4.
```

Beware that changing predefined operators it's ***bad*** practice. But I must say that I don't know if there is any standard way to add operators to is/2 evaluation....

*edit* SWI-Prolog [has a way](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/swi/library/arithmetic.pl) to add arithmetic: you get

```
?- X is 12 mydiv 6 mydiv 2.
X = 4.
```

after

```
:- op(400,xfy,mydiv).
:- arithmetic_function(mydiv/2).
mydiv(A,B,C) :- C is A div B.
```

Comment: mmm nono I have to implement a NEW division operator...I have call it div (I didn't know that it was a predeclared operator), for example I can call it: mydiv

Comment: I have try this one but don't work:

op(400,yfx,mydiv).

mydiv(X,Y,Z) :- Z is X/Y.

Some idea?

Comment: Ok, now it is more clear for me but I have some others litle doubts about the operators declaration. I have try your example and I have see that you declare the operatore in the Prolog shell launching here the 2 commands: :- op(400,xfy,mydiv). and :- arithmetic_function(mydiv/2). arithmetic_function(mydiv/2).

Can I put these commands into a prolog source code file in some way? (So I have not to declare them every time that I open my Prolog shell?)
The last question is about: :- arithmetic_function(mydiv/2). what it exactly mean?  Tnx

Comment: Yes, you can put in a source, or autoload, or from console, using `?- [user].`. About arithmetic_function, the docs are outstanding, don't you think? About meaning, I would say just *ok, it works :)*

Comment: @CapelliC about the docs, it does say `arithmetic_function` is deprecated. A working example with `arithmetic_expression_value` will be appreciated. Or is it saying that it's the  `arithmetic_expression_value` that is deprecated? I couldn't tell.

Comment: @WillNess: I think it refers to arithmetic_function. I never tried arithmetic_expression_value, and an 'usage' paragraph would be welcome.